# Is it possible to set up a database gateway for a group of database server of different type

Tags: database, server, reverse-proxy, gateway

I would like to know if it is possible to set up a database gateway (for example using haproxy) to redirect database requests to different types of DBMS:

- the gateway should expose a vip
- the gateway should route requests to two database servers (different IP adress), of the same type (for example mysql or postgresql or mariadb) on the same port (for example 3306).